# Angular DOM update performance in different cases

Tags: angular

Below are 3 different scenarios in which the data is bound to the dom in angular

**(I) Variables bound separately**

- component.ts

```
a: string = "A"
b: string = "B"
c: string = "C"
...many other props
```

- component.html

```
{{ a }} {{ b }} {{ c }}, ... and so on
```

Any update to data will be in the form:
`a = "NewA" or b = "newB", etc`

**(II) Variables bound as properties of an object and updated in place**

- component.ts

```
obj = {
   a: "A", b: "B", c: "C"
}
```

- component.html

```
{{ obj.a }} {{ obj.b }} {{ obj.c }}, ... and so on
```

Any update to data will be in the form:
`obj.a = "newA", obj.b = "newB", and so on`

**(III) Variables bound as properties of an object and updated in an immutable manner**

- component.ts

```
obj = {
   a: "A", b: "B", c: "C"
}
```

- component.html

```
{{ obj.a }} {{ obj.b }} {{ obj.c }}, ... and so on
```

Any update to data will be in the form:
`obj = {..obj, a: "newA"} or obj = {...obj, b: "newB" }, ... and so on`

Which of these three scenarios is more performant in angular when it tries to update the dom with the latest data?
Will in scenario 1 if only value for a is changed, it will only re-render that portion of html that is affected by the variable a? Will in scenario 3, updating prop a will cause all portion of dom that depend on the obj (and not just a) to re-render?

PS: Using angular 10

Answer (score 0):

If used with `OnPush` change detection strategy the 3rd option will be most performant across an app, as change detection and re-rendering will be prevented for unaffected branches of the `DOM`

I would think that 1 and 2 are be pretty much identical